# Finding a count of a relationship between two different columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following sample spreadsheet, titled "Error", linked to Power BI.

[image: Image 1]

What I need to do is figure out how many times a certain title corresponds with a certain severity. If I were to do this correctly in this case, the output would be something like the following:

*Memory Usage/Warning: 4*

*Memory Usage/Critical: 1*

*Event Log: Application/Information: 2*

*Disk Usage(E:)/Warning: 2*

I currently have one DAX function that looks like the following:

```
Memory Usage/Warning = COUNTROWS(FILTER(GROUPBY(Error, Error[Title], Error[Severity]), Error[Title] = "Memory Usage"))
```

which gives me:

*Memory Usage/Warning: 2*

I'm aware that I might need to use multiple functions to get the outputs I want so any help with even one would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use this to provide data in a format that can be copied. https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy solution that doesn't use DAX formulas: You can show counts for each combination using a matrix visual.

- Rows = Title
- Columns = Severity
- Values = Count of Severity

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Stack strongly recommends putting [table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow) and not picture.

Also, while working with DAX the rule of thumb is to use explicit measure (authored) and not implicit measure (auto-generated).

If your table has only two columns, then use this measure

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( 'Table'[Title] ), //4. get the count of the join of 2 and 3
    ALL ( 'Table' ), // 1. remove whatever is currently visible
    VALUES ( 'Table'[Severity] ), //2. what is currently visible
    VALUES ( 'Table'[Title] ) // 3. what is currently visible
)
```

If your table has more than just these two columns, then use this measure

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    //2 gets count by partition
    COUNT ( 'Table'[Severity] ),
    //1 define the partition
    ALLEXCEPT ( 'Table', 'Table'[Title], 'Table'[Severity] )  
)
```